# Elastic Search on Custom Port Number

Tags: php, rest, elasticsearch, magento-1.7, elasticsearch-plugin

I have tried by changing default port of elastic search by changing http.port no. But is not worked out. I am using php elastic library.

Due to security reason default port on my website is block.

Can any one suggest how i can proceed to run elastic search on my server.

Thank You.

Comment: you wanna change http port or tcp port???

Comment: as we are using akamai so various ports are block

Comment: Can you try to change port in both non-blocked tcp and http??? and provide the log..!

Comment: yes i have tried with all above given options but still no progress

Answer (score 0):

Did you try connecting via terminal ?

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:8080/_count?pretty' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}'
```

Replace your port instead of 8080.
*make sure you have installed curl in your system*

Comment: it is quite old post